# How to disable DVFS in kernel/kernel config?

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to disable DVFS in kernel/kernel config? How to do it?

And is there any method to confirm that I have disabled DVFS successfully.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is about Linux, consider adding the [linux-kernel] tag to attract attention from its followers.

Comment: Can this question be migrated to https://superuser.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either disable `cpufreq` entirely, or select to build only the `performance` governor for it.